# Set-SPEnterpriseSearchLinksDatabase : The search application .... did not finish loading

Tags: searchserviceapplication

I refer to [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2013/12/18/how-to-rename-search-service-application-databases-on-the-same-server) to rename Search Service Application Databases.
The Administration, Analytics Reporting and Crawl databases are successful
but the Links Store databases no work,

> Set-SPEnterpriseSearchLinksDatabase : The search application
>   ‘f4ffa287-db94-479e-82aa-88689eec0e4f’ on server xxxx did not finish
>   loading. View the event logs on the affected server for more
>   information

I have tried:
`Get-SPDatabase | Where{$_.Exists -eq $false}`

`Get-SPDatabase | Where{$_.Exists -eq $false} | ForEach {$_.Delete()}`

`PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures`

I still can not rename the Links Store databases.

Comment: Is there anything listed in the SharePoint log or the event log to provide more detail?